# How to make sure that a pod that is deleted is restarted after specified time?

Tags: kubernetes, restart

I've got a pod that restarts immediately. When I delete the pod `kubectl delete pod <pod_name>` it restarts immediately. However, I want this pod to be restarted after 1 min when I perform the delete operation.

`kubectl delete pod <pod_name>`... it waits 1 minute then it restarts running again.

To clarify, I don't want `--grace-period` flag where it waits for specified time. I want to delete pod immediately, and make it run again after 1 minute without manual intervention. Is it applicable to do?

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is not only not possible, but it also goes against one of the best qualities of Kubernetes, which is its resiliency.

The reason your Pod tries to be rescheduled (after failure or voluntary shutdown) is because it is being managed via ReplicaSet.

> A ReplicaSet's purpose is to maintain a stable set of replica Pods running at any given time. As such, it is often used to guarantee the availability of a specified number of identical Pods.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicaset/

What you could do is create a Pipeline (Jenkins, GitLab, GitHub, whatever you prefer...) where you uninstall the Deployment/StatefulSet, wait some time and reinstall the Deployment/StatefulSet.

Comment: This answer suggests the potential of a custom Kubernetes operator, with a custom resource type that replaced Deployment/ReplicaSet for this use case, and corresponding controller code that created the Pod after a delay.  But that's something you'd have to build yourself and not something built into Kubernetes.